# how to get response first key value

Tags: javascript, ajax

How can I get the first pair of key value from ajax returned json?
Like in console, if I input `response[0]` to get testdaa101.com ?

```js
.ajax({
  url: "/fetch_bar",
  type: "post",
  dataType: "json",
  async: true,
  success: function(response) {#
    response = {
      testdaa101.com: "30",
      testbb101.com: "50"
    }
    var len = Object.keys(response).length;
    var selects = document.querySelectorAll("select[id=select_host]");
    if (len == 1) {
      for (var index = 0; index < selects.length; index++)
        if (selects[index].value == response[0])
          alert("hello")
        else if (len > 1) {
          for (var ind = 0; ind < len; ind++) {
            for (var index = 0; index < selects.length; index++)
              if (selects[index].value == response[ind]) {
                alert("nice")
              }
            // if (response[0]){ alert
```

Comment: Instead of getting the length, `Object.keys(response).length`, get the keys like `Object.keys(response)`. Then get the first key from the array and the value for that key? Or, if it supported in your browser, you could use use [`Object.entries(response)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: You reset your response in your succes handler?

Comment: @Wimanicesir I imagine that's supposed to be commented, judging by the `#` before it (albeit incorrect), but I didn't want to change OP's code based on that assumption.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys` to get keys, and then take the first:

```js
const fakeAjax = () => new Promise((res) => {
  setTimeout(() => res({
    first: 1,
    second: 2
  }))
})

fakeAjax().then(data => {
  console.dir(Object.keys(data)[0]);
})
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, seems it get all return value as a pair key value. but i only want a key instead. but no worry , I use back dictionary so issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFirstPair(response) {
   var keyValuePairs = Object.entries(response);
   if (keyValuePairs.length) return { [keyValuePairs[0][0]]: keyValuePairs[0][1] };
   return {};
}
getFirstPair({
  "testdaa101.com": "30",
  "testbb101.com": "50"
})
```

This would return `{testdaa101.com: "30"}`. But the order of key value pairs in a JSON object is not consistent. So be cautious on that point